# Lua library needs to be compiled with compat support

Tags: linux, lua, centos, centos6

What's missing?

```
$ cd /var/tmp
$ wget http://lsyncd.googlecode.com/files/lsyncd-2.1.4.tar.gz
$ tar xzvf lsyncd-2.1.4.tar.gz
$ cd lsyncd-2.1.4
$ export CFLAGS="-march=native -O2"
$ sudo ./configure && make && make install

$ Lua library needs to be compiled with compat support
```

I suspect it's liblua-5.1-dev, which wouldn't install with this error:

```
$ yum install liblua-5.1-dev

$ No package liblua-5.1-dev available.
```

Comment: `yum install lua-devel`?

Answer (score 1):

When you compile Lua you can specify some COMPAT flags.
With that flags you can access to some features that have been removed from current version of Lua.
E.g. If you specify LUA_COMPAT_MODULE when build Lua 5.2 then there was `module` function.
Some Lua modules does not support your Lua version without some of this flags.
So you can rebuild your Lua or patch your Lua module ot try latest source https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd.

Comment: how would i actually do this from the command line? sort of a linux noob

Comment: I am use only windows. But to download latest source you can use `wget https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/archive/master.zip` `7z x lsyncd-master.zip` `cd lsyncd-master` and then try build.